# use id/object strategy to save data but still save the order

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my weather app, I am using Redux as my state manager. I have a list of weather locations to show in a list. The order in the list should be preserved.

I know  I have two ways:

1) use a simple array to save the weather records, but it's gonna be much harder to add (taking care of duplications), update and delete, but the order is reserved

2) use the newer fashion and save the list like `{1:{id:1,...},2:{id:2,...},...}` and this way I can benefit from the object nature and do that add, delete and update much easier and faster but of course, the order is not maintained,

So i did the old trick and added `_` to the keys `{_1:{id:1,...},_2:{id:2,...},...}` so the IDs are not number type anymore so the order is kinda untouched, BUT now that I need to display the data object from end to start i have a problem to read the object backward.

P.S. I don't like that suggestion saying save your data in an object and then the order of IDs in another array as it doesn't make sense to me as it even needs more job to be done in comparison with just a simple array having the whole data. Once I also wanted to use that `new Map()`  but found out that it's not recommended by Redux folks,

So:

1) any new strategy in the community to benefit from the id/object data store style and still have the order reserved?

2) if you think i should stick to my `_` trick, how can I display the object from the last added item to the first?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. An ordered collection is just that--I'm not sure what perceived complication(s) exist in updating/etc. a list like that.

Comment: I could not figure out your requirement. Why don't you post your code and ask the question about the specific problem you are facing?